# Can the browse history on a co-worker's computer be found or linked to my browse history on my Android?

Tags: google-chrome, android, history

Can the browse history on a co-worker's computer be found or linked to a browse history on an Android?

I was looking for a recipe on the browser of my husband's Android that I asked he look up for me and found some questionable sites.  He said it must have come from what a co-worker was looking for...and that the company computers and phones were linked.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @Ramhound I hear where you're coming from, but in this case it is a bit of a grey area and given the easeness of the answer, I think this one should be allowed.

Comment: I sincerely apologize...I am not savvy to any of the protocols/lingo.  Forgive me.

Comment: @LPChip - There is an entire Stack Exchange community dedicated to Android questions.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, but when it comes to android vs windows, they often redirect users to SuperUser.

Comment: This is, as mentioned, in that fuzzy area. This is asking if there can be an unknown connection between a computer and phone, exactly the criteria we use to decide whether a question about a phone is on topic. This question is *just* inside our scope for that reason, and the fact it was asked here rather than [android.se] is up to the original posters discretion.

Comment: I've never seen an environment where a google search history from another person's computer will sync with another persons Android account.  Unless they're all using one account, seems very unlikely due to how Android works, this really isn't possible.   the only case would be if the coworker was using the husband's computer directly. Google sync doesn't work like the OP's husband said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, if you use the Your Phone app in windows. This will essentially link a phone to windows to share notifications, and it can share things like browser pages too.

In addition, it is possible to use Chrome on your phone and computer, and use the same account and link them too.